# Python Error Chatgpt Bot Aiogram and Openai

Tags: openai-api

I created a ChatGPT bot and a DALLE2 bot. When I switch to DALLE2 mode, everything works fine and DALLE2 responds. However, when I switch to ChatGPT mode and ask a question, it still responds with DALLE2. I don't know how to create a mode where the first DALLE2 bot completes and switches to ChatGPT, and vice versa.here is the code https://github.com/aleksfolt/chatgpterror

I don’t know how to make this mode, I tried to ask chatgpt itself, but it didn’t help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.